# Replace a color in a rectangular region

Tags: imagemagick

How to replace a color inside a rectangular region of an image with Image Magick ?

Below are samples of input & output images, which I've generated with Adobe Photoshop by selecting a rectangular area (containing the grid region) and executed the command: `Image -> Adjustments -> ReplaceColor` and choosing the black color to be replaced by the gray color.

Note that, the green trace can have any shape and color (except black) and the green pixels cover the black pixels, so `floodfill` is out of the question.

Input:
[image: Input image]

Output:
[image: Output image]

I know how to replace the color in the entire image, like this:

```
magick.exe convert in.png -f fuzz 0% -fill "rgb(64,64,64)" -opaque "rgb(0,0,0)" out.png
```

But the above replaces all the black color with gray, even the black text, such as the "Ch1 Start 9 kHz" and that text can be anything (it is variable). I want the text above and below the grid region to stay black.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite simple if your input images are all the same dimensions and your crop zone is always the same. With ImageMagick you can make a clone of the input image inside parentheses, work that clone in certain ways, then composite that modified clone over the original input. A command like this should get you pretty close...

```
magick input.png ^
    ( +clone -crop 0x808+0+98 -fuzz 20% -fill "rgb(128,128,128)" ^
    -opaque "rgb(0,0,0)" -geometry +0+98 ) -composite result.png
```

That starts by reading the input image. Then inside the parentheses it makes a clone, crops just the part you want to modify, replaces all the black in that piece with gray, and sets the geometry so that clone can be composited over its original location. After that, outside the parentheses it composites that clone back onto the input image and writes the output.

Since you're using ImageMagick v7, unless you have a need for IMv6 behavior you should use just "magick" and not "magick convert".

That command is in Windows syntax using IMv7. For *nix you'll have to change the continued-line carets "^" to backslashes "\" and escape the parentheses "(...)" with backslashes "\(...\)".

EDITED TO ADD:

You can accomplish this same task using "-region" in a command like this...

```
magick input.png -region %[w]x808+0+98 -fuzz 20% ^
   -fill "rgb(128,128,128)" -opaque "rgb(0,0,0)" +region result.png
```

That isolates a given area of the image with "-region", does the modifications to just that area, then un-sets the area with "+region".

Note the use of the "%[w]" to specify the width. IMv7 can use FX expressions in many places that weren't possible with IMv6.

Comment: If you use `-region 1278x808+0+98` instead, you can get rid of all the cropping, cloning, parentheses, geometry and compositing.

Comment: Can't think of any examples right now, but I've encountered a few situations where "region" didn't behave the way I expected. It's probably just a habit for me to crop and composite.

Comment: `-region` works for me, so please make it an answer or add it to the answer and I will accept it as THE answer.  BTW: Verified with ImageMagick v7.0.10-24 Q8 x64 2020-07-18 on Windows7 x64.

Comment: I added a solution using "-region" as an edit to my answer above.